# Joining the points in a scatter plot

Tags: matplotlib

I’ve a scatter plot which almost looks like a circle. I would like to join the outer points with a line to show that almost circle like shape. Is there a way to do that in matplotlib?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ConvexHull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) from `scipy.spatial` to find the outer points of your scatter plot and then connect these points using a [PolyCollection](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) from `matplotlib.collections`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

length = 1000

#using some normally distributed data as example:
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, length)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, length)

points = np.concatenate([x,y]).reshape((2,length)).T
hull = ConvexHull(points)



ax.scatter(x,y)

ax.add_collection(PolyCollection(
    [points[hull.vertices,:]],
    edgecolors='r',
    facecolors='w',
    linewidths=2,
    zorder=-1,
    ))



plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result of the given code]

**EDIT**

Actually, you can skip the PolyCollection and just do a simple line plot using the hull vertices. You only have to make the line circular by appending the first vertex to the list of vertices (making that list one element longer):

```
circular_hull_verts = np.append(hull.vertices,hull.vertices[0])
ax.plot(
    x[circular_hull_verts], y[circular_hull_verts], 'r-', lw=2, zorder=-1, 
    )
```

**EDIT 2**:

I noticed that there is an example in the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) that looks quite similar to mine.

Comment: Woooooaaaaaahhh